# cannot see logins subfolder

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Forgive me for my lack of dba experience but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I'm working remotely on a third party to a client that asked for a login, I created the login but there's problems with it.

When I decided to modify the login, I remote in and I can't see the logins subfolder under security, it's replaced with a users subfolder.

I'm using the same windows authenticated login I used on-site. So either there's some restrictions to remoting in, or the client's dba changed something.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about *Object Explorer* within SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) then it sounds like you've drilled in too far to the tree-view.

Server principals (***Logins***) can be found under:

**Server Name** -> **Security** -> **Logins**

You got to ***Users*** because you did the following:

**Server Name** -> **Databases** -> *YourDatabaseName* -> **Security** -> **Users**